# Как правильно пишется однопрацентная слитно или раздельно

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется однопрацентная слитно или раздельно

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: однопроцентный, сложное слово, исходное сочетание "один процент".

Если вы напишете "одно процентный", то это будет наречие "одно", отнесенное к прилагательному "процентный", но такого наречия нет.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, вы имели в виду слово ***однопрОцентный*** (от слова ***прОцент***). Если я вас правильно понял, то пишется слитно.

[Словарь](http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/odnoprocentniy/?q=532&n=83216)

Answer (score 0):

Слово "однопроцентный" пишется слитно, так как имеет два корня "одн" и "процент",
О - соединительная гласная. И обязательно безударная непроверяемая "О" после "р".